# Should I commit css and js generated by laravel mix?

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, workflow, laravel-mix

I started using laravel mix, and there's huge files generated by it. Should I commit those to the repo? What are the advantages and cons of both ways?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not add anything to the repo that can be generated at any time, for example after pull. 
A clear well known example that can be added to your predicament, is `node_modules`. They can always be generated by `npm install`, therefore it should always be added to .gitignore

Answer (score 6):

Reasons you **should** commit these files:

1. No need to install node modules bloat on the production server (less security risks);
2. Much faster deployment. Just pull your changes and everything is there;
3. You don't need to keep node/npm versions in sync so compiled scripts are always identical on your machine as on production;

Reason why you **should not** commit:

1. Less files in version control (nicer diff/log);
2. You don't need to remember to compile scripts for production before deployment;
3. No merging issues (if you work in a team) for the compiled files.

If I'm working alone on a project and don't do very frequent deployments, I'd choose to commit these files.

If you have a decent deployment pipeline which can build these files on-the-fly when you need to deploy, then I would definitely not commit them.